# How to use MapMyIndia API in angular?

Tags: angular6, mapmyindia-api

i am confused on how to use MapMyIndia Api in my angular project can anyone help?

i am using the map api of getting the polygon but how to use it in angular is there any package to install?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a sample for `MapmyIndia Angular` on their Github account.

- [mapmyindia-angular-sample-webSDK-REST](https://github.com/MapmyIndia/mapmyindia-angular-sample-webSDK-REST)  (Angular)
- [mapmyindia-pureJS-sample-webSDK-REST](https://github.com/MapmyIndia/mapmyindia-pureJS-sample-webSDK-REST)  (pureJS)

If you face a problem, you can ask follow up questions here. Do feel free to use the issues tracker on GitHub to report any bugs

Comment: as we are using this     <script src="https://apis.mapmyindia.com/advancedmaps/v1/<Map_Key>/map_load?v=1.3"></script> in our index.html. this will expose our API key in browser, is there any other way to solve this issue

Comment: @pankajmalik from what I know, they do support IP binding and Domain binding so that even if the key does get exposed, it cannot be misused. Also I think *(not sure)* they also support OAuth 2.0 where in you can use an auth token which would refresh after some duration. Maybe one of these two approaches would be able to help you. That being said, I think you should just reach out to their customer support and I am quite sure they'll be able to help you out with it.